# Laravel api ускорение

Tags: laravel

Написан небольшое api сервер на laravel. Интересует вопрос, как можно его ускорить. Удалить ненужные middleware, провайдеры и т.д. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: использовать lumen

Comment: можно посмотреть в сторону roadrunner https://roadrunner.dev/docs/integration-laravel. Но в первую очередь надо оптимизировать саму логику, где это возможно (n+1 запросы, кеширование и т.п.)